# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'produk.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `produk` where `produk`.`id` = 65 limit 1)

Tags: php, laravel

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column
>   not found: 1054 Unknown column 'produk.id' in 'where clause' (SQL:
>   select * from `produk` where `produk`.`id` = 65 limit 1)

I do not know where the error is
following my code that shows the error:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, $this->aturan, $this->pesan);

    $produk = produk::find($id);
    $produk->nama_produk = $request['nama'];
    $produk->id_kategori = $request['kategori'];
    $produk->harga_jual = $request['harga'];
    $produk->update();

    return Redirect::route('produk.index');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $produk = Produk::find($id);
    $produk->delete();
    return Redirect::route('produk.index');  
}
```

Comment: Can you share your mysql table schema (SHOW CREATE TABLE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Eloquent documentation, if your model is using a different primary key than `id` you have to configure this. Eloquent expects the primary key to be `id` and that it is an autoincrementing integer by default.

```
YourModel extends Eloquent ...
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'yourOtherKey';
    ...
}
```

> "Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a protected `$primaryKey` property to override this convention."
>
> "In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an `int` automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must set the public `$incrementing` property on your model to `false`. If your primary key is not an integer, you should set the protected `$keyType` property on your model to `string`."

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Eloquent - Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead findOrFail

```
$produk = produk::findOrFail($id);
```